# How to specify multiple instances of same type of parent parser in argparse

Tags: python

Some apps I am converting from Perl to Python have quite a clever system of argument parsing where command options with specified leading substrings ("prefixes"), such as `'-xyz-..'` are identified and handled as part of standard sets. So this seems a good fit for the Python "parents" facility of `argparse`.

However, the Perl code also allows multiple instances of the same type of standard set, and it isn't obvious if or how this `argparse` parent facility can be extended to deal with that.

So what I need is something like:

```
from xyz import parser # instance 1 (options start -xyz1-..)

from xyz import parser # instance 2 (options start -xyz2-..)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[xyz1.parser, xyz2.parser])

...
```

So in this rough code outline need some way to

1. Indicate each instance of the same class uniquely, and
2. indicate within each class the unique prefix of the options it is supposed to deal with.

Comment: Please provide actual code, not pseudo-code, that demonstrates the problem you are having. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . In particular, your `import` statements are identical. Why do you expect them to refer to distinct objects? Your names `xyz1` and `xyz2` are undefined. To what do they refer?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply Rob, but my problem is not about code syntax (although as a python newby I will find an example of working code in a reply useful!). As I said, that "pseudo-code" was intended only as a sketch to give a rough idea what I wanted to do; berhaps it would have been better to omit it. Studying the argparse documentation further, I wonder if the "group" facility might not also be relevant to my problem.

Comment: I *think* I see what you are asking for. You want `import` to be parameterized, and you want multiple `import`s to re-import the module. Python doesn't work that way.  Modules are only ever imported once, regardless of multiple `import` statements, and you can't pass parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do what you want.

#### main.py:

```
import argparse
import xyz1
import xyz2

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="My program",
    parents=[xyz1.parser, xyz2.parser])
parser.add_argument("-s", "--sky")
parser.parse_args(["--help"])
```

#### xyz1.py

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="XYZ1 args", add_help=False)
parser.add_argument("-xyz1-cat", action='store_true')
parser.add_argument("-xyz1-dog", action='store_true')
```

#### xyz2.py

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="XYZ2 args", add_help=False)
parser.add_argument("-xyz2-lizard", action='store_true')
parser.add_argument("-xyz2-spock", action='store_true')
```

#### Result:

```
$ python main.py 
usage: main.py [-h] [-xyz1-cat] [-xyz1-dog] [-xyz2-lizard] [-xyz2-spock]
               [-s SKY]

My program

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -xyz1-cat
  -xyz1-dog
  -xyz2-lizard
  -xyz2-spock
  -s SKY, --sky SKY
```

### Edit

Based on OP's comment, "*I would like just one xyz.py module that can be parametrized*", this might be what he wants:

#### main.py

```
import argparse
import xyz

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="My program",
    parents=[xyz.parser("xyz1"), xyz.parser("xyz2")])
parser.add_argument("-s", "--sky")
parser.parse_args(["--help"])
```

#### xyz.py

```
import argparse

def parser(prefix):
    result = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    result.add_argument("--%s-cat"%prefix, action='store_true')
    result.add_argument("--%s-dog"%prefix, action='store_true')
    return result
```

Comment: Yes, I had a feeling it would be pretty much like that. The only thing is I would like just one xyz.py module that can be parametrized to use a prefix specified by the importing code, and in the latter (the "main" script) import two instances of this, specifying the unique prefix for each.

Comment: Modules are singletons. One cannot "import two instances" of a module. You could import a module, which module contains a class or a function that you can invoke with parameters, and then invoke that function twice.

Comment: See my edit to my answer for a module with a parameterized `parser` function.

Comment: Very many thanks Rob. I've marked yours as the preferred answer,